# Is there such constraints (Hibernate Validator) that can use class fields?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I have class:

```
public class QueryFilterDTO {

@NotEmpty
private List<String> senders;

@NotEmpty
private List<String> subjects;

private Date startDate;
private Date endDate;

@NotEmpty
private List<String> countries;

@NotEmpty
private List<String> companySizes;

public QueryFilterDTO() {

}
```

And I need to do Date validation: `startDate` *mustn't be greater than* `endDate`.
But I didn't find something like that in [HV](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-defineconstraints-spec).

Should I implement it myself? ([custom constraints](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints))

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is like this:

```
@PrePersist
protected void validateDates() {
  if(startDate.after(endDate){
  //throw a new custom validation exception..
  }
}
```

Comment: How I can throw exception like it does Hibernate Validator? (for example when NotEmpty field is empty).

Comment: To test and see if it actually works you can just do something like: throw new RuntimeException("startDate must not be later than endDate");

Comment: PrePersist is too late. I need to validate object before(during) creation, but not before write to DB.